# Two notifications from MediaSessionCompat

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediasession

My app can play music from the internet. For control, I use a push notification with buttons for pause/play and rewind. I create it via `NotificationCompat Builder` and set the `MediaStyle`. On the lock screen, MediaSessionCompat displays a full-screen notification for monitoring. But there is also a duplicate of the first notification. Because of this, I have two notifications on the lock screen.
Perhaps the MediaSession itself should hide the notification by its id or channel? I tried setting `VISIBILITY_SECRET` to the channel and notification, but it also displayed on the lock screen.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59571617/154306

Answer (score 0):

This may be behavior specific to your phone; I would first start by checking what the behavior is on an emulator.

Perhaps you'd like to compare how you're registering your MediaSession in the notification against the [Universal Android Music Player Sample](https://github.com/android/uamp). In particular, check if you've set the MediaSession token with the MediaStyle notification using [`setMediaSession()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.MediaStyle#setMediaSession(android.media.session.MediaSession.Token)); you can find how this is accomplished inside UAMP [inside `UampNotificationManager`](https://github.com/android/uamp/blob/99e44c1c5106218c62eff552b64bbc12f1883a22/common/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/media/UampNotificationManager.kt#L70).